# JSON_encode not working with GROUP_CONCAT database selection

Tags: php, javascript

I'm breaking my brain on a array from a query in MYSQL that i want to pass to a javascript array.

In the query i select the array with a GROUP CONCAT and the outcome looks like:

```
1358121600,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1358380800,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1358640000,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1360454400,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1360972800,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

But if i use JSON_Encode like this:

```
<?php echo 'var prijzen = new Array('.json_encode($array_prijzen).');'; ?>
```

I looks like the array is filled and i can also alert the array, but if i alert prijzen[0] it gives "undefined".

Comment: What does the output look like? I suspect you are ending up with some extra quotes.

Comment: yep, if i look the source code of the page it looks like:

Comment: var prijzen = "1358121600,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1358380800,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1358640000,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1360454400,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1360972800,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0";

Comment: In this case, you can skip json_encode. The problem is that its getting treated as a string and is quoted as such. You want your code to be a list of numbers within an array constructor.

Comment: yep, in combination with New Array() this is working, thanks!

Comment: If you're going to json_encode it, why not use JSON.parse on the javascript side?

Comment: What is your query? and result could you show in a nice tabular format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should fix your problem:

`<?php echo 'var prijzen = ['.$array_prijzen.'];'; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Building on @datasages 's answer.  If `$array_prijzen` is a genuine php array, then the following will work. I think datasages's answer is based on the fact that your variable named `$array_prijzen` is actually a string (which seems to be the case).  But if it's an array, then do the following (i created a five element array as an example):

```
<?php $array_prijzen = array(1358121600,1,1,0,0); echo 'var prijzen = ['.implode(",",$array_prijzen).'];'; ?>
```